# OpenCL void pointer arithmetic - strange behavior

Tags: pointers, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, amd-processor

I have wrote an OpenCL kernel that is using the opencl-opengl interoperability to read vertices and indices, but probably this is not even important because I am just doing simple pointer addition in order to get a specific vertex by index.

```
uint pos = (index + base)*stride;
```

Here i am calculating the absolute position in bytes, in my example pos is 28,643,328 with a stride of 28, index = 0 and base = 1,022,976. Well, that seems correct.

Unfortunately, I cant use `vload3` directly because the offset parameter isn't calculated as an absolute address in bytes. So I just add `pos` to the pointer `void* vertices_gl`

```
void* new_addr = vertices_gl+pos;
```

`new_addr` is in my example = 0x2f90000 and this is where the strange part begins,

`vertices_gl` = 0x303f000

---

The result (`new_addr`) should be 0x4B90000  (0x303f000 + 28,643,328)

I dont understand why the address vertices_gl is getting decreased by 716,800 (0xAF000)

---

I'm targeting the GPU: AMD Radeon HD5830

Ps: for those wondering, I am using a printf to get these values :) ( couldn't get CodeXL working)

Comment: At first glance, I feel like it should be `base + index * stride`. But other than that, I don't see anything wrong here assuming `vertices_gl` is a pointer, and pointer arithmetic works the same in OpenCL as it does in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no pointer arithmetic for `void*` pointers. Use `char*` pointers to perform byte-wise pointer computations.

Or a lot better than that: Use the *real* type the pointer is pointing to, and don't multiply offsets. Simply write `vertex[index+base]` assuming `vertex` points to your type containing 28 bytes of data.

**Performance consideration:** Align your vertex attributes to a power of two for coalesced memory access. This means, add 4 bytes of padding after each vertex entry. To automatically do this, use `float8` as the vertex type if your attributes are all floating point values. I assume you work with position and normal data or something similar, so it might be a good idea to write a custom struct which encapsulates both vectors in a convenient and self-explaining way:

```opencl
// Defining a type for the vertex data. This is 32 bytes large.
// You can share this code in a header for inclusion in both OpenCL and C / C++!
typedef struct {
    float4 pos;
    float4 normal;
} VertexData;

// Example kernel
__kernel void computeNormalKernel(__global VertexData *vertex, uint base) {
    uint index = get_global_id(0);
    VertexData thisVertex = vertex[index+base];   // It can't be simpler!
    thisVertex.normal = computeNormal(...);       // Like you'd do it in C / C++!
    vertex[index+base] = thisVertex;              // Of couse also when writing
}
```

Note: This code doesn't work with your stride of 28 if you just change one of the `float4`s to a `float3`, since `float3` also consumes 4 floats of memory. But you can write it like this, which will not add padding (but note that this will penalize memory access bandwidth):

```
typedef struct {
    float pos[4];
    float normal[3];  // Assuming you want 3 floats here
} VertexData;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer :) But does opengl do some automatic buffer alignment or something like that? I am using an vertex type array now just as you said, but I still get wrong values.. When I am using `VertexType vertex1 = vertices_gl[indices.x+base];` in OpenCL I get wrong values, but when I am doing the same in my C++ program (using the raw pointer to the same buffer) I get the correct result

Comment: okay turned out that printf is just printing the wrong values :(

Comment: So it works now? Just remember: When aligning your attributes, make sure you use the same alignment on the host, in OpenCL and in OpenGL.